# ADODB insert blank spaces

Tags: sql, asp-classic, ado

I'm calling a stored Procedure in classic asp

I'm adding my parameter like that :

```
set objParam =.CreateParameter("@Param",129,1,"3" ,Request.Form("Param"))
.Parameters.Append objParam
```

And in my sql like this

```
 @NomCentre varchar(3)
```

But when my data get inserted i've always have extra space to complete the length of my varchar

Example : "i" become "i  " 
And "te" become "te "

someone have an idea thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's probably the way the data is coming back from Request.Form, in which case:

```
trim(Request.Form("Param"))
```

might fix it.

**Edit**

Your datatype is wrong: 129 is adChar, you want 200 (adVarChar), so it's padding the field with spaces.

See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/ado/met_comm_createparameter.asp) for details.

Comment: Don't think so because before using a stored proc I was building my query and there was no space